# How to parse a duration string into seconds with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a user input string for duration (into seconds) with Javascript.

Here are some example inputs that I'd like to be able to deal with:

- "1 hour, 2 minutes"
- "1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes"
- "1d 2h 37m"
- "1 day 2min"
- "3days 20hours"

The key components are 1) days, 2) hours 3) minutes, but some components may not always be included.

My plan of attack is to use .match and regex. As long as I can get the first letter of the word, I'll know what the preceding number is for and be able to handle all the different formats of the words (e.g. hours, hour, hr, h). However, since I'm learning regex for this, it's turned out to be much more complicated than I thought.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is the order of days/hours/minutes in your string guaranteed?  If not, it may be easier to just do a separate RegEx for each.  Something like this?

```
function getSeconds(str) {
  var seconds = 0;
  var days = str.match(/(\d+)\s*d/);
  var hours = str.match(/(\d+)\s*h/);
  var minutes = str.match(/(\d+)\s*m/);
  if (days) { seconds += parseInt(days[1])*86400; }
  if (hours) { seconds += parseInt(hours[1])*3600; }
  if (minutes) { seconds += parseInt(minutes[1])*60; }
  return seconds;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Handles everything I throw at it and is very clean. Thanks a ton!

Comment: wouldn't be better to return NaN in case there was no match at all, you know, to disambiguate ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use optional substrings in the regex to match any combination as you describe:

```
/(\d+)\s*d(ays?)?\s*(\d+)\s*h(ours?)?\s*(\d+)\s*m(in(utes?)?)?/
```

This requires at least a `d`, `h`, and `m` but accepts common shortenings.

Comment: It looks like he needs it to work even if not all of d, h, and m are present.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to break your string into a number, followed by a unit string:

```
function getPieces(str) {
    var pieces = [];
    var re = /(\d+)[\s,]*([a-zA-Z]+)/g, matches;
    while (matches = re.exec(str)) {
        pieces.push(+matches[1]);
        pieces.push(matches[2]);
    }
    return(pieces);
}
```

Then function returns an array such as `["1","day","2","hours","3","minutes"]` where alternating items in the array are the value and then the unit for that value.

So, for the string:

```
"1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes"
```

the function returns:

```
[1, "day", 2, "hours", 3, "minutes"]
```

Then, you can just examine the units for each value to decide how to handle it.

Working demo and test cases here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kT9qn/.  The function is tolerant of variable amounts of whitespace and will take a comma, a space or neither between the digit and the unit label.  It expects either a space or a comma (at least one) after the unit.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes";

var seconds = 0;
str.replace (/\s*,?(\d+)\s*(?:(d)(?:ays?)?|(h)(?:ours?)?|(m)(?:in(?:utes?)?)?)/g, function (m0, n, d, h, m) {
  seconds += +n * (d ? 24 * 60 * 60 : h ? 60 * 60 : 60);
  return m0; 
});
```

Here I use replace not to change the string but to process the matches one by one. Note days, hours aminutes can be in any order.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a function that accepts practically any way you could write out a duration of time, and returns the equivalent number of milliseconds.

**Order doesn't matter**:

```js
function string_to_milliseconds(str, take_sum = false) {
    const units   = {
        yr: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(Y)/i                     , s: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 }, // Case insensitive "Y"
        mo: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(M|[Mm][Oo])/             , s: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *  30 }, // Case insensitive "mo" or sensitive "M" 
        wk: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(W)/i                     , s: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *   7 }, // Case insensitive "W" 
        dy: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(D)/i                     , s: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24       }, // Case insensitive "D"
        hr: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(h)/i                     , s: 1000 * 60 * 60            }, // Case insensitive "h"
        mn: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(m(?![so])|[Mm][Ii]?[Nn])/, s: 1000 * 60                 }, // Case insensitive "min"/"mn" or sensitive "m" (if not followed by "s" or "o")
        sc: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(s)/i                     , s: 1000                      }, // Case insensitive "s"
        ms: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(ms|mil)/i                , s: 1                         }, // Case insensitive "ms"/"mil"
    };

    return Object.values(units).reduce((sum, unit) => sum + (str.match(unit.re)?.[1] * unit.s || 0), 0);
}
console.log( string_to_milliseconds("2h 1Day 4 minutes 65sec") );
```

---

### An Over-Engineered Solution

This function accepts pretty much any input format I could think of, including ISO Durations (e.g. `T10h40m`), ISO timestamps (e.g. `2022-10-14 10:40`), and both short and long hand representations (e.g. abominations like "`2 days 4hr 1m`" parse properly).

When using short or long hand representations, order doesn't matter and the function even handles duplicate units with the parameter `take_sum`. When `take_sum` is true, the sums of the duplicated units are used, otherwise only the first occurrence of a unit is used.

```js
/** Converts a timespan in the form of a string to the equivalent number of milliseconds
 * @param   {string} str       String containing units of time (eg. 1y, 2 days, 1min, etc.)
 * @param   {bool  } take_sum  If true, returns the sum of duplicated units in str
 * @returns {number} Timespan in Milliseconds
 */
function string_to_milliseconds(str, take_sum = false) {
    const units   = {
        yr: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(Y)/i                     , s: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 }, // Case insensitive "Y"
        mo: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(M|[Mm][Oo])/             , s: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *  30 }, // Case insensitive "mo" or sensitive "M" 
        wk: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(W)/i                     , s: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *   7 }, // Case insensitive "W" 
        dy: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(D)/i                     , s: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24       }, // Case insensitive "D"
        hr: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(h)/i                     , s: 1000 * 60 * 60            }, // Case insensitive "h"
        mn: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(m(?!s|o)|[Mm][Ii]?[Nn])/ , s: 1000 * 60                 }, // Case insensitive "min"/"mn" or sensitive "m" (if not followed by "s" or "o")
        sc: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(s)/i                     , s: 1000                      }, // Case insensitive "s"
        ms: { re: /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\s*(ms|mil)/i                , s: 1                         }, // Case insensitive "ms"/"mil"
    };

    /** Convert from ISO format 
     * 
     * The follow special cases are also parseable as an ISO format: 
     *      123 08:12   -> 123 days 8 hours 12 minutes
     *      08:12:32    -> 8 hours 12 minutes 32 seconds
     *      2022/01/23  -> 2022 years 1 month 23 days
     *      12:32:09.09 -> 12 hours 32 minutes 9 seconds 90 milliseconds
     */
    str = str.replaceAll(/(?<!:)(?:(?<yr>\d+)[/-](?<mo>\d+)[/-])?(?<dy>(?<=[/-])\d+|\d+(?=[T ]))?[T ]?(?:(?<hr>\d+):(?<mn>\d+)(?:[:](?<sc>\d+\.?\d*))?)?(?!:)/g, function(...args) {
        const units = args.lastItem;

        let out = [];
        for (let unit in units) {
            if (!units[unit]) continue;

            out.push(`${units[unit]}${unit}`);
        }
        if (out.length == 0) return args[0];
        return out.join(' ');
    })

    /** Convert from H:m:s format
     * 
     * There are 3 cases: hh:mm, hh:mm:ss, and the generic case,
     * where the generic case accepts between 4 and 7 colon-delimited sections, with the rightmost 
     * is always seconds, and each section moving left increases to the next larger time unit 
     */
    if (str.match(/\d+:\d+/)) {
        let time = str.split(":")
        switch (time.length) {
            case 2: 
                str = `${time[0]}hr ${time[1]}min`; 
                break;
            case 3:
                str = `${time[0]}hr ${time[1]}min ${time[2] ?? 0}sec`;
                break;
            default:
                let types = Object.keys(units).reverse().slice(1).filter(u => u != "wk"); // Weeks are not used in this time format
                str = time.reverse().map((t, i) => `${t}${types[i]}`).join(' ');
                break;
        }
    }

    /** Convert from time string to milliseconds
     * 
     * Given the format of <numeric value> <time unit>, each value-unit pair is converted 
     * to equiivalent milliseconds, before taking the sum of all converted pairs
     */
    return Object.values(units).reduce(function(sum, unit) {
        const parse = (m) => m?.[1] * unit.s || 0;
        return sum + ( !take_sum ? parse(str.match(unit.re))
                                 : str.matchAll?.(RegExp(unit.re, unit.re.flags + "g")).reduce((ms, m) => ms + parse(m), 0) || 0 );
    }, 0);
}
console.log( string_to_milliseconds("1 year 22:90:20 1week") );
```

I also created a function to reverse the process:

```js
/**
 * Expands a given number of milliseconds into it's string representation
 * @param   {number} ms
 * @returns {string}  
 */
function milliseconds_to_string(ms) {
    const ranges = {
        years        : 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365,
        months       : 1000 * 3600 * 24 *  30,
        // weeks        : 1000 * 3600 * 24 *   7,
        days         : 1000 * 3600 * 24,
        hours        : 1000 * 3600,
        minutes      : 1000 * 60,
        seconds      : 1000,
        milliseconds : 1,
    };

    let parsed = {};
    for (let unit in ranges) {
        parsed[unit] =  Math.floor(ms / ranges[unit]);
        ms          -= parsed[unit] * ranges[unit];
    }

    return Object.entries(parsed)
        .map(time => time[1] ? `${time[1]} ${time[0]}` : ``).filter(t => t)
        .join(", ").replace(/((?<!\d)1 \w+)s/g, "$1");  // Un-pluralize singular units
}
console.log( milliseconds_to_string(88220000) );
```

I ran a few test cases below, though you can also check out the whole script on CodePen: https://codepen.io/williamrwilkins/pen/VwRbNdM

```
{
    "14:20": {
        "str_to_ms": 51600000,
        "ms_to_str": "14 hours, 20 minutes"
    },
    "25:10:11.232": {
        "str_to_ms": 90611232,
        "ms_to_str": "1 day, 1 hour, 10 minutes, 11 seconds, 232 milliseconds"
    },
    "1:2:3:4:5:6.007": {
        "str_to_ms": 36993906007,
        "ms_to_str": "1 year, 2 months, 3 days, 4 hours, 5 minutes, 6 seconds, 7 milliseconds"
    },
    "1month 2days 3 hours 4 mins 5 seconds": {
        "str_to_ms": 3801600000,
        "ms_to_str": "1 month, 14 days"
    },
    "530 days": {
        "str_to_ms": 45792000000,
        "ms_to_str": "1 year, 5 months, 15 days"
    },
    "1 year 2M 3wk 4 days 5HR 6min 7 seconds 8 ms 2 milliseconds": {
        "str_to_ms": 8917560000,
        "ms_to_str": "3 months, 13 days, 5 hours, 6 minutes"
    },
    "12 hours 1 day ": {
        "str_to_ms": 1123200000,
        "ms_to_str": "13 days"
    },
    "1.5 days": {
        "str_to_ms": 129600000,
        "ms_to_str": "1 day, 12 hours"
    },
    "36 hours": {
        "str_to_ms": 3110400000,
        "ms_to_str": "1 month, 6 days"
    },
    "4s l6orem 5 days ips3um": {
        "str_to_ms": 432004000,
        "ms_to_str": "5 days, 4 seconds"
    },
    "NaN seconds": {
        "str_to_ms": 0,
        "ms_to_str": ""
    },
    "5 days 59 mins 2 days 1 min": {
        "str_to_ms": 5788800000,
        "ms_to_str": "2 months, 7 days"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general version of the accepted answer that accepts months and seconds as well.

```js
const getSeconds = str => {
    let seconds = 0;
    let months = str.match(/(\d+)\s*M/);
    let days = str.match(/(\d+)\s*D/);
    let hours = str.match(/(\d+)\s*h/);
    let minutes = str.match(/(\d+)\s*m/);
    let secs = str.match(/(\d+)\s*s/);
    if (months) { seconds += parseInt(months[1])*86400*30; }
    if (days) { seconds += parseInt(days[1])*86400; }
    if (hours) { seconds += parseInt(hours[1])*3600; }
    if (minutes) { seconds += parseInt(minutes[1])*60; }
    if (secs) { seconds += parseInt(secs[1]); }
    return seconds;
};
```

Comment: And yet, this solution is not over-engineered enough. The [bash `times` builtin](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3b6bd19457e260b65d11f2712ec3da56cef463f/lib/sh/timeval.c#L176) uses a locale-defined comma separator, and can output durations like "0m1,500s" to mean zero minutes, and one and a half seconds - this solution will understand it as "500000 milliseconds", instead of "1500 milliseconds"