# How to convert custom string datetime value (1d 14h 7m) to digital minutes value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have array of strings that looks like:

`"1d 14h 7m", "5h 14m", "14h 0m", "16h 12m"`.

This strings represent dates (days, hours and minutes) for orders turnaround time in my table. Values only can have days, hours and minutes.

How to convert this values to digital minutes representation, for example to 2156 minutes in JavaScript?

How to convert minutes value (2156 for example) back to my format "1d 14h 7m" in JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267156/javascript-calculate-average-time-for-arrays-with-datetime-string-values ?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see how an what to ask here. HINT: Show some effort and ask specific questions about where you got stuck the the code you wrote

Comment: Check a similar question: [How to parse a duration string into seconds with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909457/how-to-parse-a-duration-string-into-seconds-with-javascript)